# Preparing satellite image input for classification in Weka

Tags: weka, landsat

I am very new to Weka and want to use it for Land cover classification using random forest. However I don't know how to make satellite image inputs to be used in Weka. I have Landsat-8 image and polygon shapefiles describing land cover classes in the image tile. 
whatsoever I read on net, I understood that we need to develop "training" and "test" set of Landsat image in ARFF format to be used in Weka but the issue is how to do it.

thank you!

Comment: This is not possible in a default Weka installation. There *is* an Image Processing Extension (called ("imageFilters") for Weka (which you can install via the package manager) but I don't think this approach makes sense for beginners. (You have to know a lot about weka, and substantial, very specific image preprocessing needs to be done)

Comment: Thank you knb, this is still helpful, well I can do these processing in ArcGIS/ENVI however doing it in Weka is an issue, do you have any kind of document regarding it? Thanks again